# Update não funciona ao tentar atualizar um <p:panelGrid>

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um botão que fica dentro de um `<p:toolbarGroup>` onde realizo algumas operações, também tenho um `<p:panelGrid>` que deveria ser renderizado após o usuário clicar no botão, mas não consigo atualizar esse componente. Eu consigo atualizar a tabela e os valores do `toolbarGroup` porém o resto não.

Código do botão:

```
<p:commandButton value="Gerar Relatórios" style="margin-left:10px"
        actionListener="#{relatorioBean.gerarRelatorio()}"
        rendered="#{relatorioBean.listaVazia == true}" id="btnGerar"
        update=":msgGlobal :frmPrin:arquivoTable :frmPrin:pnlCadastro" />
```

PanelGrild:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" id="pnlCadastro"
        style="width:100%;margin-top:20px" columnClasses="rotulo, campo"
        rendered="#{relatorioBean.listaVazia == false}">
```

Como podem ver esse  painel só é renderizado quando a condição é falsa, porém quando clico no botão a condição muda para false, só o painel que não atualiza mesmo.

O componente só é atualizado após um `F5`. Por que o update não está funcionando? Será que estou esquecendo de algo?

Comment: já tentou o `process="@this"` no botão?

Comment: Já sim @Rafael, não funcionou e também dá erro nos processos. Eu to fazendo um teste e a condição do renderer está como false, mas ele não aparece. kk

Comment: Olha, aqui está quando eu entro no sistema, lá embaixo estou exibindo a variável boolean: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iSfyI.png

Comment: Depois que eu clico no botão ela vira FALSE, agora que era pra aparecer o painel mas ele não aparece: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Opk.png

Comment: Estranho que o até o update do `<h:outputText>` tá funcionando

Comment: Bom, primeiramente, cuidado com os *inlines* na sua codificação, eles não são tidos como boa prática. ;) Certifique-se de que a lista que você está pegando esteja recebendo um valor do bean. Talvez (dependendo do escopo que você tenha definido no backing bean) ela esteja sendo resetada ou até mesmo não tenha sido inicializada. Espero ter ajudado. P.S: Não fiz um comentário na sua pergunta por falta de reputação.

Comment: A lista está funcionando corretamente e os `inlines` são para testes.

Comment: Sei que é meio trivial, mas já tentou jogar um system.out no get dessa lista que tá no backing bean?

Comment: Você está atualizando um componente não renderizado. Atualize o componente pai do seu panelGrid. Se não quiser atualizar o form todo, englobe-o em um `p:panel` e então atualiza tal panel.

Comment: Já sim, e se a lista não tivesse funcionando minha dataTable não seria preenchida

Comment: Tenta isolar ele em um outro form ou em um <h:panelGroup>.

Comment: Era isso mesmo @Rodrigo responda a pergunta para que eu possa marca-la como correta.

Comment: Já resolvi o problema obrigado

Comment: @Techies Poderia postar a solução como resposta?

Comment: Estou esperando pra ver se o @Rodrigo responde pois ele que me ajudou nos comentários

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando atualizar um componente - utilizando o `update` - que ainda não está renderizado. Mesmo que na ação atual ele altere a condição do `rendered` para verdadeira.

Para resolver isso, o `update` deve ser feito no componente pai do que ainda não foi renderizado. 
Aconselho englobá-lo em um `<p:panel>` e informar o respectivo id no `update` do seu `commandButton`.